# Create internal proxy server to transfom proxy with credentials into proxy without credentials

Tags: c#, .net, proxy-server

There is excellent library `HttpToSocks5Proxy` which allows easy use of Socks proxy server in .NET requests, but it also has additional functionality - **creates internal HTTP proxy server**, which can be used during application working. For example, we have a Socks proxy:

```
username:password@101.102.103.104:1234
```

When we pass it to `HttpToSocks5Proxy`, it creates HTTP proxy, e.g. (`127.0.0.1:54321`) (port is random), it doesn't require credentials and passes all traffic through initial Socks5 proxy.

I would like to ask how to make similar functionality but **for HTTP proxy with credentials**. In other words, if we have an HTTP proxy

```
username:password@201.202.203.204:2345
```

our code creates internal proxy (`127.0.0.1:54321`) without credentials and passes all traffic through initial HTTP proxy.
I found some examples, but only for Socks proxy. I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: You can use [YARP](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/) to create reverse proxies in .NET. It seems you need [Direct forwarding](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/direct-forwarding.html) that uses a WebProxy with credentials instead of `UseProxy = false`

Comment: Do you really need a proxy though? You can set the [WebProxy property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy?view=net-7.0) to your HttpClient or HttpWebRequest objects. You can set up a default proxy for all calls through app.config/web.config with the [defaultProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings) element

Comment: It's needed for specific component, which only works with proxy which doesn't require credentials. For HttpClient and HttpWebRequests surely I would use WebProxy property.

Comment: I assume you can't modify the source? Otherwise you could add the WebProxy you need. In that case the direct forwarding example may be useful